# Use Rdl with SQL Server CE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce, rdl

I was searching in google but so far I could not find any solid result about, wheather I could
use rdl with SQL Server CE version in vs2010?

And I thought maybe you guys know something about it!

cheers